# Alternate way of configuring data sources in quartz scheduler properties file

Tags: quartz-scheduler

We are configuring the Quartz Scheduler data sources as specified in the documentation that is by providing all the details without encrypting the data base details. By this the data base details are exposed to the other users and any one who have access to the file system can easily get hands on.

So are there any other ways to provide the data sources details using API or provide the database details by encrypting and providing the details as part of quartz.properties file

Answer (score 0):

On class "StdSchedulerFactory" you can call the method "initialize(Properties props)" to set needed propertries by API. Then you don't need a property-file. (See: [StdSchedulerFactory API](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/impl/StdSchedulerFactory.html))

Example:

```
    public Scheduler createSchedulerWithProperties(Properties props) 
                                               throws SchedulerException {
            StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
            return factory.getScheduler();
    }
```

But then you have to set all properties of SchedulerFactory. Also the properties, that have a default value with default constructor. (Search for 'quartz.properties' inside of 'quartz-2.2.X.jar' to get default property values of quartz.)